# Save executed Sql inside table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, insert

I am trying to log down sql that execute.

I have a function call LogGenerateReport(String Sql) that will do a insert process to save the data in a database.

The Problem i face is about the SQl ''.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(Sql)
VALUE('SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = 'ABC123';')
```

Its return me error and i know what happened because of the quote.
I try again inside my database where i open a new query and paste above sql and made some modification on it such as.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(Sql)
VALUE('SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = ''' + 'ABC123' + ''';')
```

Its return me expected result.

```
 Output:
|Sql                                          |
|SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = 'ABC123';|
```

But back on my .aspx.cs page i have a string builder that store the executed query and before it executed, it need to save the query first.

```
For example:

System.Text.StringBuilder str = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
str.append("SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = 'ABC123';");

api.LogGenerateReport(Convert.tostring(str));
```

Its return me error as like above because of the quote.

I try to figure it out to overcome this and my idea is

```
String TempSql = Convert.tostring(str);
TempSql.Replace("'","+'''");
```

I wont work because of the + symbol is at different position.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @lc. what you meant by using a parameter? can give an example?

Comment: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To succesfully log any and all SQL queries regardless of their content, you need to apply parameterized commands in the following way:

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand(someSqlConnection))
{
   command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE(Sql) VALUE(@Sql)";
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sql", "<any string>");
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

That way you can avoid escaping anything with **NON-STANDARD** methods, and protect your code from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = @Param";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = 'ABC';
```

Try this out and using paramterised one is highly recommended and to some extent handling sql injection as well as these sorts of problems

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just replace all single quotes within the statement with double single qoutes?
This request works fine:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(Sql)
VALUE('SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = ''ABC123'';')
```

And the code:

```
String TempSql = Convert.tostring(str);
TempSql.Replace("'","''");
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your api.LogGenerateReport isn't escaping single quotes when inserting the row into the database.  You should fix your insert statement using paramaters.

To get it to "work" as is, you need to escape your single quotes with two single quotes.  Try changing:

```
"SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = 'ABC123';"
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = ''ABC123'';" <-- these are 2 single quotes, no double quotes
```

Good luck.